# Simple way to download JSON from URL in Objective C

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, json

I am using a php file to connect to a MYSQL database and return a table from the database in a JSON format.

Here is the link to the PHP file which displays the JSON result: http://tradersdb.rf.gd/service1.php

I have tried many variations of objective C code to download this JSON formatted information into an objective C array but have had no success. I am hoping for this code to be used in an IOS application that will read from the MYSQL database.

I feel as though the issue however, is with the PHP file and potential incorrect JSON formatting rather than any of the Objective C code. I have used json_encode() in the PHP file. All help is appreciated.

Comment: You can go to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate your JSON against different standards.

Comment: I have tried doing this by pasting the URL before and it suggests that there are errors but I am not sure why as I have used the standard json_encode function from PHP so I don't know how to proceed if formatting is the issue could you try pasting the URL on jsonformatter and see for yourself?

Comment: The server is not allowing the AJAX to fetch the JSON: "This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support". Just paste the response of the JSON manually into the text area and attempt to validate.

Comment: Yes when I paste just the response into the formatter it suggests that the JSON is correct however, once again I have been unable to retrieve that correct response in any way through objective-c. The only way I have even been able to see the response is simply through the browser by going to the URL. I am trying to work out how I can get that correct response that is displayed in the browser downloaded in objective-c.

Comment: An interesting idea would be that I've tried to fetch that URL on several different JSON validating sites. Each one returns the same error: "This site requires Javascript to work...". Could it be that your JSON is indeed valid, but you are not able to fetch it because of the server settings?

Comment: Do you have any idea what setting may be causing this or how I could potentially go about solving it?

Comment: Change hosting. I've provided my reasons in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some tests on the JSON link you provided, turns out your web server does inject HTML in front of the actual content. This HTML is meant to set a cookie via JavaScript and then automatically load the actual data.

The problem is not with your JSON, but your web framework. You'll see below that the page loads `aes.js` from your root directory, which is most likely used for the decryption/encryption of the cookie.

Here is the HTML returned:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"></script>
    <script>
        function toNumbers(d) {
            var e = [];
            d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
                e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
            });
            return e
        }

        function toHex() {
            for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
            return e.toLowerCase()
        }
        var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
            b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
            c = toNumbers("db90ed280d6dd97b2c5a2f1352115adf");
        document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
        location.href = "http://tradersdb.rf.gd/service1.php?i=1";
    </script>
    <noscript>
        This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support
    </noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

It's most likely a bot protection plugin on your server. If you have control over your server plugins, you should disable / remove it. The only other options are to either find a better host which allows plain content access or find a way to disable this server setting.

**Update:**

It would appear this is a free hosting server. I would strongly suggest you move off this and you will find that your code works. If it's a free host, you probably can't disable it. In that case, this host provider is useless for you and you should search for a new one.